# Save and parseInt user input in one line of code? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, parseint

Here's my code:

```js
function add() {
  var num1 = prompt("Enter 1st number")
  var num2 = prompt("Enter 2nd number")
  parseInt(num1);
  parseInt(num2);
  var result = num1 + num2;
  alert(result);
}
add();
```

I'm trying to build a simple addition calculator. parseInt wasn't working and an answer here said to declare the variable like `var num1 = parseInt(num1);`. However since I'm only getting "num1" through user input (`var num1 = prompt...")`, not sure how to store it as integer, or parseInt, in the same line. Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have here are standalone, unused expressions:

```
parseInt(num1);
parseInt(num2);
```

Those evaluate to numbers, but you don't *use* them, so they're useless. Either assign them to variables, eg

```
const actualNum1 = parseInt(num1);
const actualNum2 = parseInt(num2);
```

and then use those variables, or just wrap the `prompt` in `parseInt`:

```
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Enter 1st number"))
var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Enter 2nd number"))
```

Unless you're intending to only accept integers, consider using `Number` instead:

```
var num1 = Number(prompt("Enter 1st number"))
var num2 = Number(prompt("Enter 2nd number"))
```

Comment: Thank you. Your second and third code snippets are exactly what i was looking for. Getting the user input, storing it, and making sure it's an integer, all in a single line.

Comment: Do have a question though, what does it mean that `parseInt(num1)` is a standalone unused expression? I thought the parseInt function is working on the var "num1" and updating it as an integer?

Comment: If the `parseInt` is alone on its own line, you create a number from the string, but then you don't store that created number anywhere - you don't store it in a variable, or pass it to some other function, or anything like that, so it doesn't do anything. Consider enabling [no-unused-expressions](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions)

Comment: There's also `+prompt("Enter 1st number")` or `alert(+prompt("num1:") + +prompt("num2:"));` for everything on one line

Comment: @Tzvi2 values are passed to function calls not the variable itself, so functions on their own dont know where the value came from so their is no way for it to update the variable with the new value. Even if they knew the name native function code is out of scope of the variable and have no access to change it. Which is why they return the value and you have to manually store it.